# tensor flow defined precise mini batch

Tags: tensorflow

I have a database, in which I cut with numpy my variable X and my variable to guess, or 'predict': Y

my question is about the definition of training data batches. Indeed,

I have a column in my database called "classes" which informs that this or that student is part of this or that class.

If I want to cause the tensorflow to make predictions class by class, I have to define as "training mini batch" the different values ​​presented in this column?

(ex: class_1, class_2, class_3) But these classes are obviously never the same size: / so how to tell him to take just the line for one value of the column "classes" and cut by class so that he can finally receive a whole class of student and he can to make predictions on the scale of a class such as for example (which pupil progresses the fastest in chemistry, which is promised to a literary future etc etc).

I hope, are clearly formulated in my approximate English, and thanks to you if you have to take the time to decipher some things.

If clarification can help you to answer me effectively I am available do not hesitate.

There is the code, i put you my accuracy too, which is don't move :(  :

```
        #coding:utf-8
    # Import les librairies necessaires:
    import statsmodels as stat
    import seaborn as sbrn
    import pandas as pd 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import sqlite3
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from tensorflow import keras
    import tensorflow as tf

    # Connexion a la base de donnée:
    conn=sqlite3.connect("t15.db")

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///t15.db')

    def init_variables():

        weights = np.random.normal(size=18)
        bias = 0 
        return weights, bias

    def pre_activation(features,weights,bias):

        return np.dot(features, weights) + bias

    def activation(z):

        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    def derivative_activation(z):

        return activation(z) * (1 - activation(z))

    def predict(features, weights, bias):

        z = pre_activation(features, weights, bias)
        y = activation(z)
        return np.round(y)

    def cost(predictions, targets):

        return np.mean((predictions - targets)**2)

    def train(features, targets, weights, bias):

        epochs = 100
        learning_rate = 0.1

        # Imprimer la precision:
        predictions = predict(features, weights, bias)
        print("Accuracy = ", np.mean(predictions == targets))

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                predictions = activation(pre_activation(features, weights, bias))
                print("Cost = {0}".format(cost(predictions, targets)))

            # Initialiser les gradients:
            weights_gradients = np.zeros(weights.shape)
            bias_gradients = 0

            # Traverser chaque itération, chaque ligne de la DB:
            for feature, target in zip(features, targets):

                # Calculer la predicton:
                z = pre_activation(feature, weights, bias)
                y = activation(z)
                # Mettre à jour le gradients:
                weights_gradients += (y - target) * derivative_activation(z) * feature
                bias_gradients += (y - target) * derivative_activation(z)
            # Mettre à jour les variables:
            weights = weights - learning_rate * weights_gradients
            bias = bias - learning_rate * bias_gradients
            # Imprimer la precision:
            predictions = predict(features, weights, bias)
            print("Accuracy = ", np.mean(predictions == targets))


    # Creation de notre DataSet:
df = pd.read_sql_table("performances",engine, index_col='id', columns=['nom_cours','name_student','date_cours','prof','frere_soeur','option','parent','age','heure_cours','nb_de_cours','moyenne','meilleur_note','temps_controle','nb_controle','sexe','place'])
    df.loc[:, 'date_cours'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_cours)

    X = df.iloc[:,-16:-1].values
    Y = df.iloc[:,-1].values

    # Codage de la variable indépendante:
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
    labEncr_X = LabelEncoder()

    # Passer les variable en Dummy
    X[:,0] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
    X[:,1] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,1])
    X[:,2] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,2])
    X[:,3] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,3])
    X[:,4] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,4])
    X[:,12] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,12])
    X[:,13] = labEncr_X.fit_transform(X[:,13])

    # Passer les variable en Dummy de trap
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[2])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[3])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[4])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[12])
    onehotEncr = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[13])

    X = onehotEncr.fit_transform(X).toarray()

    # Variable dépendante:
    labEncr_Y = LabelEncoder()
    Y = labEncr_Y.fit_transform(Y)

    features = X
    targets = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

    # Construction des echantillons de test et de training:
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size= 0.2, random_state = 0)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # dataset

        weights, bias = init_variables()

        print(features[0])
        print(features[1])
        train(features,targets,weights,bias)
```

Accuracy :

```
[0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 5.1000e+01 3.1000e+01
 0.0000e+00 1.8900e+02 2.2100e+02 2.1000e+03 7.4100e+01 7.0000e+00
 1.3470e+01 1.0000e+00 4.8000e+04 1.7024e+05 1.0000e+00 1.8000e+01]
[0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 1.0000e+00 5.1000e+01 6.0000e+01
 0.0000e+00 1.6700e+02 6.8000e+01 2.1000e+03 7.3600e+01 7.0000e+00
 1.3470e+01 2.0000e+00 4.8000e+04 1.7436e+05 1.0000e+00 1.8000e+01]
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Cost = 0.7910174152153987
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Cost = 0.7910174152153987
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Accuracy =  0.20898258478460127
Cost = 0.7910174152153987
```

Thank you a lot for your interest people ! :)

Comment: Welcome to  stackoverflow. Please ask only one question at a time. Also it is ok if your english is not perfect, no need to apologize.

Comment: Bonjour Lazare, bienvenue à SO. Honestly I haven't understood your issue completely. Could you post the code which you've tried to solve your problem and the related error messages or wrong results. I also encourage you to shorten your description a bit. Maybe you could split your question into smaller ones? Merci beaucoup.

Comment: you'r right it's too long, can i put the code in a comment ? 

my problem is that the training is done on all the lines without distinction. For example, he compares all the pupils in the school to train, whereas he would have to classify class by class (a school class, students).

Comment: Sure you can place your code in a comment. Nevertheless the best is to put it directly into your issue (use `edit` below). Thanks.

Comment: hmn, i tried to make it shorter, i have other questions but one at a time eheh :) my code is at the end, there is probably a lot missing  x)

Comment: erf nobody friends with tensorflow ?

Comment: if somebody has any idea i still have this problem ...

Comment: Heck, it's a basic question, I do not find people who know about tensorflow, even on the discord or other forum in French nobody touches this bookstore it's crazy ...